# If let - Multiple conditions

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, option-type

Can I use multiple conditions of let obj = something in IF

```
if let u = custom["u"] as? String || let url = custom["URL"] as? String
{
// Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple conditions, but only if you use AND conditions.

If you use an `OR`, you have no idea which of your value was properly set and thus cannot access properly the variables.

With an `AND` test, you are sure that both variable were properly created, so you know with certainty their type.

You have to write the tests separated with a comma separator :

```
if let u = custom["u"], 
   let url = custom["URL"] {
    // Do something here
}
```

Also, you can add some conditions directly after your  `if let` block , using the `where` keyword :

```
if let u = custom["u"] where u == "testValue", 
   let url = custom["URL"] {
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your collection type is `Dictionary`.

If you really want to use `OR`:

```
if(custom.keys.contains("u") || custom.keys.contains["URL"]) { }
```

But as already others wrote, that doesn't really make sense, because if you need values for those keys, you still have to write two seperate if statements.

```
if let u = custom["u"] {
    print("Value for u: \(u!)");
}

if let url = custom["URL"] {
    print("Value for URL: \(url!)");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1) it has no sense with OR
2) for AND use , instead

```
if let u = custom["u"] as? String,
let url = custom["URL"] as? String {
// Do something here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with user3441734. Whty would you want to do that?

```
if let u = custom["u"] as? String { 
    if let url = custom["URL"] as? 
    // Do something here
    }
}
```

I would do it this way. The inner block gets only executed when the above condition is true or:

```
 if let u = custom["u"] as? String { 
     // Call same method 
 }
 if let url = custom["URL"] as? 
     // Call same method 
 }
```

This way the two will be checked and executed.